# working with none english text in firefox extension (addon)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

This is the code that I have in javascript file inside my addon:

```
 function ShotText() {
      var inputString = "שלום"; //Hebrew letters
      alert(inputString);             
}
```

When I run this function using addon I get this:
[alt text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/8782/shalom2.jpg](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/8782/shalom2.jpg)

But if I run the same code without addon (regular javascript function), I get this:
[alt text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/5236/shalom1.jpg](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/5236/shalom1.jpg)

Where is the problem?

Maybe I need to set encoding somewhere inside the extension?

Comment: Could it possibly be some Unicode problem?

Comment: I don't know you tell me, how to set it right. If it works in regular js it should work with addon i think.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/International_characters_in_XUL_JavaScript explains the behavior in detail. Note that this is a wrong thing to do anyway, since the user-visible strings should be in the extension's `locale`, so that the extension could be translated to other languages.